# Color Gradient for Three.js line

Tags: webgl, three.js

I only can find THREE.LineBasicMaterial(). Is there a way to have a simple color gradient from point a to point b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Vertex & fragment shaders for change color for vertices[0] and vertices[1]. (Line points)
See http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_lines.html