# Multi-stop Gradient in THREE.js for Lines

Tags: javascript, three.js, gradient

This shows an example of how to create a two-color gradient along a THREE.js line:

[Color Gradient for Three.js line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589274/color-gradient-for-three-js-line)

How do you implement a multi-stop color gradient along a line?  It looks like attributes will only interpolate across two values (I tried passing in three, it only worked with the first two values).

Comment: you will need custom shader or divide the line into multiple vertices

Answer (score 3):

This is the do-it-yourself color gradient approach:

Create a line geometry and add some vertices:

```
var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeometry.vertices.push( 
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 0 ), 
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 10, 0 ) 
);
```

Use some helper functions for convenience:

```
var steps = 0.2;
var phase = 1.5;
var coloredLine = getColoredBufferLine( steps, phase, lineGeometry );
scene.add( coloredLine );
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfd58hbm/

---

Explaination:

`getColoredBufferLine` creates a new buffer geometry from the geometry, which is just for convenience. It then iterates the vertices, assigning each vertex a color. The color is calculated using another helper: `color.set ( makeColorGradient( i, frequency, phase ) );`.

Where basically `frequency` defines how many color changes you want the line to receive.

And `phase` is a shift of the color spectrum (= what color does the line start with).

I have added a dat.gui so you can play around with the parameters. If you want to change the color repetition or type, you can alter the `makeColorGradient` function to your needs. This page offers some good explaination how gradients are generated and where my example is based upon: http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php.