# How to apply a gradient to a curved line in Three JS?

Tags: three.js

I'm looking for a way to apply a color gradient to a curved line. The examples I have found apply a color to each line segment, but my curved line doesn't have any vertices or segments on the `curveGeometry` object, it just has points in the `curveGeometry.position` property.

Below is my function for creating my line, with a fixed color of `0x00AAFF`. How do I apply a color gradient to this thing?

```
createLine() {
    // Create a curve from the points
    var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(this.points);

    // Get the points
    var curvePoints = curve.getPoints(this.pointCount);

    // Create the buffer geometry from the points
    var curveGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curvePoints);

    // Create a material for the line
    var curveMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color : 0x00AAFF,
    });

    // Create the line with the geometry and the material
    var line = new THREE.Line(curveGeometry, curveMaterial);

    return line;
}
```

This question addresses this problem for a line using vertices, but my line does not have vertices:

[Multi-stop Gradient in THREE.js for Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830779/multi-stop-gradient-in-three-js-for-lines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-stop Gradient in THREE.js for Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830779/multi-stop-gradient-in-three-js-for-lines)

Comment: @Marquizzo my line does not have vertices so I can't use that same technique

Comment: Ah, since you're using BufferGeometry, then this solution will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589274/color-gradient-for-three-js-line